# ignore.synchronization=true/ browser.waitforAngularEnabled(true) takes so long when compared to browser.sleep()

Tags: protractor, wait

While executing e2e tests in protractor when we are using `ignore.synchronization=true`/ `browser.waitforAngularEnabled(true)` to handle waits is too slow when compared to `browser.sleep(10000)` to proceed to next step. How to address these kind of wait issues to make the script execution faster?

Comment: Having Protractor wait until the angular page has stabilized is one of Protractors most useful features so I feel it is a bad idea to disabled for the entirety of your testing and will likely cause you more pain. I would troubleshoot why the application is taking so long to load? Does it take this long on every page or are some quicker? Is the big delay between all actions?

Answer (score 0):

**Difference:**

`ignore.synchronization=true/ browser.waitforAngularEnabled(true)` are used to make protractor wait until all the angular modules are loaded.

`browser.sleep(// time in ms)` is raw way of stopping the protractor for the given particular `ms`.

**Solution:**

To handle wait issues:

use `browser.waitforAngularEnabled(false)` after getting your base url. Then you can use `expected waits` which makes the protractor wait until that expectation is completed.

Refer https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions for more details

Hope it helps you

Comment: That kind of waits are called in explicit waits